# Why are colours lighter when using my own theme in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have created my own theme in Flutter but when I try to use these colours they are much lighter on the emulator. I'm new to Flutter so I'm not sure of the best way to create a theme but the colours do appear. What is the best way to set your own theme or why would the colours be lighter?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

extension CustomPrimaryColorScheme on ColorScheme {
  Color get primaryColor => const Color(0xfffa4659);
  Color get accentColor => const Color(0xfff0fff3);
  Color get watermelonLight => const Color(0xffFFF0F1);
}
extension CustomColorScheme on ColorScheme {
  Color get aqua =>const Color(0xff11cbd7);
  Color get paleAqua => const Color(0xffc6f1e7);
  Color get ice => const Color(0xfff0fff3);
  Color get watermelon => const Color(0xfffa4659);
  Color get brownGrey => const Color(0xff979797);
  Color get charcoal => const Color(0xff313939);
  }
```

```
backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.watermelon;
```